# Substring length failed (takes more than is set to take)

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, truncate, power-automate

I have a Microsoft Flow that has failed with the following message:

```
Body
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Invalid Mashup Expression using supplied values.\r\n inner exception: Microsoft SQL: String or binary data would be truncated.",
}
```

I know what this means, in this case, it's about a SQL column that has a nvarchar(2000) set as a limitation. I take care of this in my flow before inserting it with an "SQL insert action". I convert the HTML (from email) to a text (source is 5024 long),

after this I check (condition) if the length is greater than 1999 (it is greater so it goes into the Yes part), there I take a substring of this 5024 long string like this "`substring(body('converetedHTML'),0,1999)`" (note that this works for all previous runs) but for some reason, for this 1 Flow it takes 2023 instead of 1999 hence the error message.

On each step it has what it's supposed to have except on the SQL insert action, the value of this variable that has 1999 becomes 2023. No idea how this can be.

Can anyone suggest me things to look for, or help me out because according to me this is a "malfunctioning" and not a logical mistake but I could be wrong, anyway I want to figure this out?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Perhaps there are multi-byte characters in the HTML?

Comment: It is always better to insert into single column in a staging table and can write expressions after that for bifurcation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick , Thank you for pointing that out, this was indeed the issue, there where "\n" in the content and this was causing the +X amount over the limit that was set.

Thank you very much !